# How do I run Flash player in the latest Chrome (v52) on Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, flash, linux

I get the below message when I try to view a video in the 'Cisco packet tracer course' (a online course having flash video content):

[image: Flash]

Clicking that, it takes me to the Adobe website that gives options to choose how to download the plugin.

1. I tried the Ubuntu Software Center option, which on clicking opens the Software Center, but then nothing pops up.
2. I tried download the tar.gz and placing the .so file (that you get after extracting the tar file) in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins and /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/ folder, restarted the browser, but I still see the above message.

I have gone through many posts over the Internet, and they all show one of the above steps.

Numerous post on support.google says to check `about://plugins` page and enable the flash plugin there, but I don't see any such listing on that page
(https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/eGxBLqt87Z0).

[image]

I am now out of options; what is the issue here? How do I update the Flash player plugin, in either Firefox or Chrome.

**Note:**

- Chrome version: Version 52.0.2743.116 Built on Ubuntu, running on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr)
- Firefox version: 48.0
- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Comment: Use 64 bit OS on your 64bit cpu!

Comment: @Ipor my machine is 32 bit

Comment: I know, that's the reason why i said use 64bit os. Chrome has dropped flash support for 32bit more than a half year ago. You love to install ubuntu, so install again!

Comment: ok, Thanks for your reply. So I need to search for 64 bit machine now..

Comment: your machine is already 64bit.

Comment: @IporSircer I never checked it, but really how do you know :)  ? My physcial RAM limit is 4 GB hence i thoughts its 32bit..

Comment: @IporSircer `dmidecode -t 16` return `Maximum Capacity: 4 GB`

Comment: 4gb is your motherboard/bios limit. `cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep --color lm` If you have `lm` flag, then it is 64bit. (the latest 32bit cpu was made in 2004. I'm pretty sure your pc is younger than 12years)

Comment: @IporSircer Thanks a lot. I see the `lm` flag. Learnt new things from you. :)